# Finding a line that is parallel to two planes in 3D

Tags: vectors, 3d

I have a question asking me to find a line in the symmetrical equation that passes through $(1,1,1)$ and also parallel to the following two planes

- $\pi_1 = [x,y,z] = [1,-3,4]+r[-1,3,2]+s[2,1,2]$
- $\pi_2 = [x,y,z] = [1,2,1]+r[1,-3,2]+s[1,1,2]$

I manage to find the normal equation of these two planes:

- $\pi_1 = 4x+6y-7z=-42 $
- $\pi_2 = -8x+4z=-4 $

Then I am not sure how to proceed with this question. However, we can see that these two planes are not even parallel to each other, so how can we find a line that is parallel two both of them?

The answer key provided the solution as:
$\frac{x-1}{3}=\frac{y-1}{5}=\frac{z-1}{6}$, but I drew the line in Geogebra and I do not think the line is parallel to both planes. [image]

Comment: Are you sure you calculated the correct normal form of the plane $\pi_2$?

Comment: Hmmm but I just tried with a calculator, it holds $4*1+6*-3-7*4 = -42$

Comment: Yes sorry, indeed it is correct!

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\pi_2 : -8x+4z=-4$?

Comment: Oh right, sorry for the mistake I made. I gonna change it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be parallel to both planes, the direction vector $\vec v$ of the line must be orthogonal to both normal vectors, then a direction vectors is given by

$$\vec v=\vec n_1\times \vec n_2=\begin{vmatrix}\hat i&\hat j&\hat k\\4&6&-7\\-8&0&-4\end{vmatrix}$$

Comment: Thank you for your help, I got the right equation! However, do you have any idea how my book would got the direction vector of (3,5,6)? I understand they are parallel, but by doing what calculation would render such a result directly as it is not required to simplify direction vector.

Comment: By cross product we obtain $(-24,-40,48)$ that is a multiple of $(3,5,-6)$. Therefore it seems there is a typo in the book. I think that using cross product is a very effective way in this case.

Comment: Yes indeed it is, and I can't think of any other ways to do this. Thank you very much!

Comment: @YanZhuang You are welcome! Bye